# How to insert option value on Product Custom Attribute 'manufacturer' by magento program?

Tags: magento2, product

I have 100+ manufacturer from Old database for preparing data migration to Magento 2.

How can assign manufacturer to on php for the tables eav_attribute_option_value and eav_attribute_option?

Thanks